# kafka stream global store returns null on key that was inserted

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

So I have a stream that writes to a global state store and also reads form it and in many times it is eventually consistent

I have tried his sequence :

1.) new message to the stream

2.) get key1 from global store

3.) key1 is empty write a new value to it (push to a backing topic a new message with key1)

4.) new message comes right away

5.) get key1 again from global store ... would expect it is not null as it was written in 3.
but the key1 is null again and again a new key1 is put to a backing topic of a global store

Is there any way to achieve more strictness here or I have just accept the eventually consistent nature of the global store in kafka stream?

I have tried also with **withCachingEnabled** and **withLoggingDisabled** if this could affect the performance but the same problem stays.

My global store setup

```
        StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<MappingKey, Long>> keyValueStoreBuilder =
                Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
                        Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(MAIN_MAPPING_TOPIC.getGlobalStoreName()),
                        keySerde,
                        Serdes.Long());

        builder.addGlobalStore(
                keyValueStoreBuilder,
                MAIN_MAPPING_TOPIC.getTopicName(),
                Consumed.with(keySerde, Serdes.Long()),
                () -> new GlobalStoreUpdater<>(MAIN_MAPPING_TOPIC.getGlobalStoreName()));`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this setting for your application:

```
"cache.max.bytes.buffering" : 0
```

This will ensure that your application don't keep any cache in memory and that it will flush to disk as soon as possible.

Comment: ok but this would ensure that the state is ok on local instance? or would this affect all kaska stream nodes? I mean when I execute point 3 from the sequence described up there is still some IO in between before all other instances/consumers receive the message for new state

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to say. I don't know how you deployed your app, but unless you lose the persistent disk or it gets corrupted, there will be no new state.